# Tizen cannot create file in native service application

Tags: file, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, samsung-gear-fit

I am developing a wearable application for Samsung Gear Fit 2 in Tizen 2.3. The app is hybrid type, where I need to write the sensor data obtained in native application into a file. However, file pointer is null and new file is not created. 'errno' shows the message "Permission Denied". I have checked the permissions for creating file. Also, the same code runs perfectly on Gear S2 without any error

Comment: I am writing file to path opt/usr/media/Downloads/test.csv

Answer (score 0):

Have you set right permissions ? and in which path are you writing ?

Comment: Hi RzR, I am writing file to path /opt/usr/media/Downloads/test.csv. Also, I have included the privilege http://tizen.org/privilege/mediastorage. The project seems to work fine on Gear S2 device, but does not work on Gear Fit 2

Comment: can you check permissions using sdb shell on both devices ?
I don't have GF2 but I have GS2 ... can you reproduce on emulator ? 
or share a sample code ?